# How can I insert / upload an external html file to wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This may be asked before but I couldn't find any answer which is directly related to my question.

I have a web site using wordpress theme. I want to insert an external html file to the site but I couldn't find anyway to do that.

Note: Just copying the html code doesn't work. The external html file is an R Markdown document created in RStudio. So I must find a way to directly upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a page and paste there your html code

1. Create a page on the wordpress dashboard (i.e example)
2. The default appearance of the pages is generated by page.php file located in /wp-contents/themes/YOUR THEME/ folder. Create a php file page-example.php in this folder and paste your html code
3. When you'll go to this page you'll see the htm code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Custom Page Template where you can add your own HTML code. After that you just have to choose your page template while creating a page.

[image]

Take a look this [link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/) to read more about custom page templates.